# Changes of phase in high frequency makes the speaker "clicks"

Tags: signal-analysis, phase, fsk

I modulate some data over sound in a 17.7Khz and 17.8Khz. It works like an FSK with a pulse duration of 0.015sec. When playing a string the speaker gives a very strange noise that it seems to be the phase 180 degrees change.

Is there any way to reduce this noice ?

Comment: Do you forget the phase when going across the frequency transition?

Comment: What do you mean to forget the phase?

Comment: I mean, if you generate the sinusoid by sin(phase), incrementing the phase by every sample, do you then reset the phase when you switch to a new frequency?

Comment: Ohh, thanks, now I understand it. So, you say I have to reset the phase when in the End and Start of a new freq?

Comment: No.... I just wanted to know how you do it.

Comment: Ok, is there any solution for those phase changes?

Comment: By every sample, add a phase increment that corresponds to the current frequency. You should not skip adding an increment when transitioning between frequencies. Is what you do something like this? I'm asking because that should already work pretty well, but even smoother transitions are possible. But I don't know where you're currently at.

Comment: Do you have some examples or theory to post here?

Comment: Some alternatives: crossfade at the transition, ramping the frequency at the transition, bandpass filtering the output.